# Next.js: 404 on every page using app router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, app-router

I have just started building a `Next.js` app and for some reason I get 404 on every page that I load. I have tried making random pages such as `myRandom` but still does not work! And looks like it's redirecting me to 404 but Idk

Location: `app -> myRandom.js`

Url: `http://localhost:3000/myRandom/`

Terminal:

```
   Compiling /myRandom ...
 ✓ Compiled /myRandom in 895ms (247 modules)
 ○ Compiling /not-found ...
 ✓ Compiled /not-found in 971ms (471 modules)
```

myRandom.js:

```
import React from 'react'

const MyRandom = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      random
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyRandom
```

---

**layout.js**:

```
'use client'
import StoreProvider from "@/redux/store/StoreProvider";
import "./globals.css";
import Head from "next/head";

// export const metadata = {
//   title: "Create Next App",
//   description: "Generated by create next app",
// };

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <Head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <title></title>
      </Head>
      <body>
        <StoreProvider >
          {children}
        </StoreProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

**StoreProvider.js**:

```
import React from 'react'
import { store } from './store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

const StoreProvider = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      {children}
    </Provider>
  )
}

export default StoreProvider
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Next js for the route, you need to create a folder in that folder and create a file with a page.js name like src->app->myRandom-> page.js .

when you hit http://localhost:3000/myRandom this will load.

below given example of contact page

eg.[image]